System.NotSupportedException: Versions of MySQL prior to 5.6 are not currently supported
I am not able to connect to MariaDB with EF.  I am using libraries:

MySql.Data v9.0.0
MySql.Data.EntityFramework v9.0.0

MariaDB version: 10.5.8-MariaDB-log
My app.config
 <entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
     <parameters>
       <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
     </parameters>
   </defaultConnectionFactory>
   <providers>
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
   <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
     </provider></providers>
 </entityFramework>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

I am able to connect to database
ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
ctx.Database.Connection.Close();

I am able to execute queries:
ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
var command = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "Select * from Device";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

But I am not able to do EF operations, such as:
ctx.ApplicationSettings.ToArray();

Exception Message:
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure. ---> 
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> 
System.NotSupportedException: Versions of MySQL prior to 5.6 are not currently supported
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ResolveManifestToken>b__0(Tuple`3 k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()


This question is similar to: Failed to connect to MariaDB after upgrade to version 10.11.5 from c#. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Obviously different, System.InvalidCastException is not the same as System.NotSupportedException . OP stated he can open connection, the other one is "can't open connection". This one is about EF specifically. the other one is about ADO.NET driver.

MariaDB server, up to some recent version, sends version string to the connecting client, which is similar to this "5.5.5-10.5.17-MariaDB"
This is intentional (or was intentional) on 2 reasons

"Dumb" connectors such as MySQL Connector/NET parse this version as 5.5.5
MariaDB is compatible to MySQL 5.5, so here is where 5.5 comes from
"Smart" connectors, that are aware and explicitly support MariaDB, such as MySqlConnector , parse that as 10.5.17

That works around some weirdo Oracle MySQL replication problem which, where
replicants could not handle version > 9, because they parsed first character only


So here are the alternatives:

use version=5.6.10  server parameter, to fake version and keep connector quiet. See version

Upgrade MariaDB to 11.4, server version is no more 5.5.5-whatever, it is 11.4-MariaDB

Best of all - use "smart" connector, explicitly supporting MariaDB. Not the Oracle one, as they are allegedly totally focused on MySQL server:).
MySqlConnector is a really good one, I've read the code, and contributed a tiny bit, and I was impressed by the code quality. The EF based on this connector is Pomelo, which explicitly supports multiple versions of MariaDB.



As from callstack It is not EF Core, so Pomelo and MySqlConnector is not an option.

The callstack is from MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices. It is the Oracle's connector, therefore the recommendation, to use a better connector

I mean that System.Data.Entity.Core is not EF Core. If you know how to use Pomelo with EF6, post your suggestions.

The OP said he wants to use EF, he did not ask for EF6.  I have enough other suggestions, and some of them do not include changing the MySQL Connector, although I strongly recommend to use something that was tested and proven, rather than a funny mashup of oldest MariaDB with newest, untested connector and framework support library.

Answer is good, but tag is EF6, stack is EF6. Add then best of all is to switch to EF Core ;)

worked for me : fake version number

worked on windows but not in linux

should be the same thing, faking version number is not Windows specific
